# How to autosave ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know if there's an option (or a suggested hack) to make IPython notebooks save automatically before executing a cell?

Many times I've been working on something without saving for quite some time, then I execute a stupid command that prints so much crap to the console that my browser becomes unresponsive, leading to me losing all my work.

A timed autosave might also do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development version has that feature fully implemented. Install it by following the instructions on the [ipython github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython).

Instructions form the repo:

> If you want to hack on certain parts, e.g. the IPython notebook, in a
>   clean environment (such as a virtualenv) you can use pip to grab the
>   necessary dependencies quickly:

```
 $ git clone --recursive https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
 $ cd ipython
 $ pip install -e ".[notebook]"
```

> This installs the necessary
>   packages and symlinks IPython into your current environment so that
>   you can work on your local repo copy and run it from anywhere:

```
 $ ipython notebook
```

Comment: This looks like a superb answer, unfortunately I have no clue what this is saying.  Why would someone need to clone a github repository in order to have ipython autosave?

Answer (score 0):

Updating iPython Notebook solved several problems I had with iPython Notebook; for instance, it autosaves, or auto-correction is disabled, or `%matplotlib inline` works now (before updating, I had to use `--pylab inline` in the command line when I was running `$ipython notebook`).

As I use coda on my mac, I updated iPython Notebook via conda:

`$conda update ipython`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set a lower interval for autosave feature using the following magic command:

```
%autosave 60
```

in order to save automatically your notebook every 60 seconds.